# How to Tuning 10GB for Server Generate Traffic

Tags: networking, server

I'm install Ubuntu 16.04  and add Network Card 10GB   for  Server Generate Traffic testing ([Software  packETH](http://packeth.sourceforge.net/packeth/Home.html)).

Server  ===>  Core Switch 6807 ===>  Firewall(POC)

Generate  Traffic is OK  but  it is Maximum Speed  about  1.4 - 1.6 Gbit/sec

[Graph Interface out  from Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UblOV.png)

How to Tuning Ubuntu System or  another way ??

Thank you

Comment: How did you find out that this is an Ubuntu / Linux problem ? Hwo did you configured packETH to generate Traffic ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use MTU size of 9000 to get max. speed on the wire.
You can set this value like this: (example for NIC eth0)

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 9000
```

or

```
ip link set dev eth0 mtu 9000
```

This makes sure that the maximum on bandwidth can be utilized. This is one possibility to tune network performance.
Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) is the maximum packet size that can be transmitted at one time. If you drive a truck that can transport 9000 Kilo of cargo why you want to put on only 1500 Kilo ? :-) Thats the way it works here with MTU.
Next thing is  initial congestion window parameter.

```
ip route change default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static initcwnd 10
```

But this will be not supported from every NIC driver. Here is a good explanation of initial congestion window parameter: http://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/tune-tcp-initcwnd-for-optimum-performance/

Related to the above is the sysctl setting

```
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle
```

This tells the system whether it should start at the default window size only for new TCP connections or also for existing TCP connections that have been idle for too long (on 3.5, too long is 1 second, but see net.sctp.rto_initial for its current value on your system). If you’re using persistent HTTP connections, you’re likely to end up in this state, so set net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle=0 (just put it into the sysctl config file mentioned above).

Make sure that the firewall isn't a bottleneck. Maybe you like to look on this side for

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack*
```

to tune if the FW is running on Linux too. Keep an eye on timeout-values here. Also if you use

```
iptables
```

on server-side !

Comment: Would you please explain what this setting exactly does, how to change it, why exactly the value 9000 and why you think this solves the described question?